# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "jv_commit" already exists

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, javers

I am using **Spring Data JPA and Javers** example. With the clean DB, when I run the project first time and then it works, when I run second time with hibernate:ddl-auto: create, it fails with below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaJaversApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.JpaJaversApplication.main(JpaJaversApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.ddl(SchemaManagerImpl.java:91) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.create(SchemaManagerImpl.java:52) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureTable(JaversSchemaManager.java:223) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureSchema(JaversSchemaManager.java:47) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.ensureSchema(JaversSqlRepository.java:186) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:186) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.ensureSchema(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:183) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.afterPropertiesSet(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:177) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "jv_commit" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.ddl(SchemaManagerImpl.java:88) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

**Book.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String author;

    private String title;

    private String email;
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
    Stream<Book> findAllByAuthor(String author);
}
```

Comment: Debug whats going on in `JaversSchemaManager.ensureTable()`

Comment: @BartekWalacik - `if (schemaInspector.relationExists(tableName)) {
            return;
        }` This method should return true, because table already present on the schema, due to which its failing. I'm not clear why?

Comment: use your debugger and step into `schemaInspector.relationExists(tableName)` and find out what's wrong

Comment: I checked `ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getTables(catalog, schemaName, convertCase(name), new String[]{"TABLE"});` schemaName itself coming and null and resultset is also null and thus getting error.

Comment: on which version of Postgres?

Comment: see https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/826, think about contributing a failing test case

Comment: @BartekWalacik - I'm using Postgres 11 version, However if you simple try to run the code you should be able to reproduced this error.

Comment: watch this issue https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/826

Comment: @BartekWalacik - Thanks ! Look like this has been mark as bug & fixed. In which version of Javers, this fixed can be seen ?

Comment: fixed in Javers 5.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Javers 5.6.2

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not yet fixed and can be easily seen in version 6.9.1 as well.